# Trimming string variables by reference in PHP5

Tags: php, string, pass-by-reference, trim

I saw another post suggesting using this statement to trim string variables contained in the array:

```
$_POST=array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

However, if in the first place, the strings are not contained in an array, I would like to have a trim function that can be used like this:

```
$a='  aaa ';
$b='  bbb ';
$c='  ccc ';
trimAll($a,$b,$c); //arbitrary number of string variables can be passed
```

I tried to write a function like this:

```
function trimAll() {

    $args = &func_get_args();
    foreach($args as &$arg) {
        if(isset($arg) && is_string($arg))
            $arg=&trim($arg);
    }
      //no return value is required
}
```

But without success, the string variables do not get trimmed after function return.

Why and how can this be done??

Comment: Will you need to do `trimAll(&$a, &$b);` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: variable-length argument list by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925253/php-variable-length-argument-list-by-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot pass variable number of parameters by reference. As a workaround, try something like

```
list($a, $b, $c) = array_map('trim', array($a, $b, $c));
```

better yet, rewrite the snippet so that it doesn't require to use a bunch of variables, which is a bad idea anyways

Answer (score 2):

This also works, but will likely make anyone you might happen to work with frustrated as its very unintuitive:

```
// pass variables by string name
extract(array_map('trim', compact('a', 'b', 'c')));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass a variable-length list of args by reference.

You could pass in an array of references.

```
function trimAll($array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(isset($array[$k]) && is_string($array[$k]))
            $array[$k]=&trim($array[$k]);
    }
}
```

... and suitably modify your call to create an array of references.

```
$a='  aaa ';
$b='  bbb ';
$c='  ccc ';
trimAll(array(&$a,&$b,&$c));
```

Comment: If you add prefix the argument $array in the function trimAll with &, will that then enable you to use it normally

Comment: It won't, it complains Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference on line 15
http://codepad.org/FItzMVjn

Comment: maybe I should adopt approach's stereofrog

Comment: @ken: this is not call-time pass by reference. putting references in an array is specifically allowed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that this is possible using func_get_args, though a comment on it's PHP manual page suggests one possible alternative solution: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#90095

However user187291's workaround looks far simpler.

Comment: yes, but it requires call-time pass-by-reference, which is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in the variables by Reference.

```
trimAll(&$a,&$b,&$c)
```

Comment: Call-time pass-by-reference (what you suggest) is deprecated in PHP 5.

Comment: I know its depreciated, but is it not also about the only way he can do what he wants unless there is a way of declaring that all (unknown number of) properties of a method will be passed byref

Comment: This will still not work with the `trimAll` function as it is written (have you tried it?)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but uses call-time pass-by-reference, which is deprecated in PHP 5.3:

```
function trimAll() {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($backtrace[0]['args'] as &$arg)
        if(isset($arg) && is_string($arg))
            $arg=trim($arg);
}
$a='  aaa ';
$b='  bbb ';
$c='  ccc ';
trimAll(&$a,&$b,&$c);
echo "$a\n";
echo "$b\n";
echo "$c\n";
```