# PHP: variable-length argument list by reference?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, function-parameter

Is it possible to create a PHP function that takes a variable number of parameters all of them by reference?

It doesn't help me a function that receives by reference an array of values nor a function that takes its arguments wrapped in an object because I'm working on function composition and argument binding.
Don't think about call-time pass-by-reference either. That thing shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear... mainly because there are some missing words and punctuation.

Comment: If you want an array of references (which points to other variables), then I'm not sure if this can be done in PHP (?)

Comment: Maybe the OP should come back to rephrase the question so that we are able to actually answer it. :)

Comment: Maybe you could give us an example of why passing an array or an object wrapping the elements doesn't suit you.

Comment: Btw PHP 5.6 has a new "splat operator" http://stackoverflow.com/a/21387043/632951

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PHP 5.6 introduced [new variadic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) which supports pass-by-reference. (thanks @outis for the update)

```
function foo(&...$args) {
    $args[0] = 'bar';
}
```

For PHP 5.5 or lower you can use the following trick:

```
function foo(&$param0 = null, &$param1 = null, &$param2 = null, &$param3 = null, &$param4 = null, &$param5 = null) {
  $argc = func_num_args();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $argc; $i++) {
    $name = 'param'.$i;
    $params[] = & $$name;
  }
  // do something
}
```

The downside is that number of arguments is limited by the number of arguments defined (6 in the example snippet). 
but with the func_num_args() you could detect if more are needed.

Passing more than 7 parameters to a function is bad practice anyway ;)

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing that. It seems the only solution so far. Not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: However these parameters have to be sent byref, and expressions are not allowed. Not very convenient.

Comment: "PHP has no buildin function for variable parameters by reference." is wrong after 5.6. Pls check outis's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

PHP 5.6 introduces a [new variadic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) that supports pass-by-reference. Prefixing the last parameter to a function with `...` declares it as an array that will hold any actual arguments from that point on. The array can be declared to hold references by further prefixing the `...` token with a `&`, as is done for other parameters, effectively making the arguments pass-by-ref.

Example 1:

```
function foo(&...$args) {
    $args[0] = 'bar';
}
foo($a);
echo $a, "\n";
#  output:
#a
```

Example 2:

```
function number(&...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $k => &$v) {
        $v = $k;
    }
}
number($zero, $one, $two);
echo "$zero, $one, $two\n";
#  output:
#0, 1, 2
```

Comment: To be noted that, it worked for me without the `&` before `$v` in `foreach ($args as $k => $v) `

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass all of your parameters wrapped in an object.

```
Class A
{
    public $var = 1;
}

function f($a)
{
    $a->var = 2;
}

$o = new A;
printf("\$o->var: %s\n", $o->var);
f($o);
printf("\$o->var: %s\n", $o->var);
```

should print
1
2

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
$test = 'foo';
$test2 = 'bar';

function test(){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($backtrace[0]['args'] as &$arg)
        $arg .= 'baz';
}

test(&$test, &$test2);
```

However, this uses call-time pass by reference which is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: sorry I didn't see you wanted them to be references....all you have to do is pass them as an object.

You can also pass them in an array for example

```
myfunction(array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2'));
```

then in the function you simply

```
myfunction ($arguments) {

echo $arguments['var1'];
echo $arguments['var2'];

}
```

The arrays can also be nested.

Comment: I actually am still not 100% sure what your trying to ask, but I hope I understood correctly.

Comment: The question is simple. The hard thing is to explain why passing the arguments wrapped in an array or in an object don't serve my needs (I's a thing about argument binding and function composition).

Comment: This is not correct! Arrays are passed by value in PHP.