# How can arguments to variadic functions be passed by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, variadic-functions

Assuming it's possible, how would one pass arguments by reference to a variadic function without generating a warning in PHP? We can no longer use the '&' operator in a function call, otherwise I'd accept that (even though it would be error prone, should a coder forget it).

What inspired this is are old MySQLi wrapper classes that I unearthed (these days, I'd just use PDO). The only difference between the wrappers and the MySQLi classes is the wrappers throw exceptions rather than returning `FALSE`.

```
class DBException extends RuntimeException {}
...
class MySQLi_throwing extends mysqli {
    ...
    function prepare($query) {
        $stmt = parent::prepare($query);
        if (!$stmt) {
            throw new DBException($this->error, $this->errno);
        }
        return new MySQLi_stmt_throwing($this, $query, $stmt);
    }
}
// I don't remember why I switched from extension to composition, but
// it shouldn't matter for this question.
class MySQLi_stmt_throwing /* extends MySQLi_stmt */ {
    protected $_link, $_query, $_delegate;

    public function __construct($link, $query, $prepared) {
        //parent::__construct($link, $query);
        $this->_link = $link;
        $this->_query = $query;
        $this->_delegate = $prepared;
    }
    function bind_param($name, &$var) {
        return $this->_delegate->bind_param($name, $var);
    }
    function __call($name, $args) {
        //$rslt = call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::' . $name), $args);
        $rslt = call_user_func_array(array($this->_delegate, $name), $args);
        if (False === $rslt) {
            throw new DBException($this->_link->error, $this->errno);
        }
        return $rslt;
    }
}
```

The difficulty lies in calling methods such as `bind_result` on the wrapper. Constant-arity functions (e.g. `bind_param`) can be explicitly defined, allowing for pass-by-reference. `bind_result`, however, needs all arguments to be pass-by-reference. If you call `bind_result` on an instance of `MySQLi_stmt_throwing` as-is, the arguments are passed by value and the binding won't take.

```
try {
    $id = Null;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE ...');
    $stmt->execute()
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    // $id is still null at this point
    ...
} catch (DBException $exc) {
   ...
}
```

Since the above classes are no longer in use, this question is merely a matter of curiosity. Alternate approaches to the wrapper classes are not relevant. Defining a method with a bunch of arguments taking `Null` default values is not correct (what if you define 20 arguments, but the function is called with 21?). Answers don't even need to be written in terms of `MySQL_stmt_throwing`; it exists simply to provide a concrete example.

Comment: Whoops... just found the question that this one dups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925253/php-variable-length-argument-list-by-reference, though I prefer meager's answer below to the accepted answer for the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of passing variable length argument lists by reference in PHP.  It is a fundamental limitation of the language.

There is, however, a workaround with `array(&$var1, &$var2...)` syntax:

```
<?php

/** raise all our arguments to the power of 2 */
function pow2() {
        $args = &func_get_arg(0);

        for ($i = 0; $i< count($args); ++$i) {
            $args[$i] **= 2;
        }
}


$x = 1; $y = 2; $z = 3;
pow2(array(&$x, &$y, &$z)); // this is the important line

echo "$x, $y, $z"; // output "1, 4, 9"
```

`Test` could also be declared `function test($args)` but I wanted to illustrate that this works with the `func_get_args()` family of functions.  It is the `array(&$x)` that causes the variable to be passed by reference, not the function signature.

From a comment on PHP's documentation on function arguments: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Has this changed in PHP 5.6 with the introduction of variadics?

Comment: @Mark: with such questions, it's best to check the PHP manual. Then, armed with that information, you can post a new answer.

Comment: @outis The docs actually don't say. [The RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics#by-reference_capture) recommended it, but I don't know if it made it into the official implementation or not.

Comment: @Mark: you might want to read the "Function Arguments" page more closely. At the end of the "[Variable-length argument lists ... in PHP 5.6+](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) section, it states: "Finally, you may also pass variable arguments by reference by prefixing the ... with an ampersand (&)."

Answer (score 11):

As of PHP 5.6 you **can** [pass arguments by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new#example-176) to a variadic function. Here's an example from [the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics#by-reference_capture):

```
public function prepare($query, &...$params) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
    foreach ($params as $i => &$param) {
        $stmt->bindParam($i + 1, $param);
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```