# Get argument values as reference in PHP

Tags: php, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can arguments to variadic functions be passed by reference in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612086/how-can-arguments-to-variadic-functions-be-passed-by-reference-in-php)

I need to get the values from the arguments of a `method` or `function`. I know i can do this with `func_get_args()`. But i really need to get the arguments by reference. Is there any way to do that?

I currently have this:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    function someFunc ( $arg1, $arg2 )
    {
        print_r ( func_get_args() );
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->someFunc('a1', 'a2');
?>
```

In my real code the argument values are passed to another `class->method()`. In there i want to be able to change the argument values. This would be possible if i could get the values as reference.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stopping you now .. just make it a `variable instead` if not PHP would return `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

```
class Test {

    function someFunc(&$arg1, &$arg2) {
        var_dump(func_get_args());

        $arg1 = strtoupper($arg1);
        $arg2 = strtoupper($arg2);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";

$arg1 = "a1";
$arg2 = "ar2";
$t = new Test();
$t->someFunc($arg1, $arg2);

var_dump($arg1, $arg2);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'a1' (length=2)
  1 => string 'ar2' (length=3)

string 'A1' (length=2) // modified
string 'AR2' (length=3) // modified
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
    class Test
    {
        function someFunc ( &$arg1, &$arg2)
        {
//    used the variable as per you want it....
        }
    }

    $t = new Test();
    $t->someFunc('a1', 'a2');
    ?>


    You have to add & to the arguement so that it can be used as reference...
```