# how to pass unlimited arguments by reference in php

Tags: php, function, variables, arguments, pass-by-reference

I have php function that has an unlimited number of args which I am getting from func_get_args(). I have some operations with arguments (changing string or doing something) and I want this to be like a passing argument by reference. is it possible?

example:

```
$test = 'foo';
$test2 = 'bar';

function test(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $arg)
        $arg .= 'baz';
}

test($test, $test2);
```

Answer (score 20):

Since PHP-5.6 you can use a [variadic](http://php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) reference:

```
function test(&...$args) {
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        $arg .= 'baz';
    }
}
```

Comment: Flawless and 5.6 support, can't love this answer more, thanks for updating !

Answer (score 11):

As answered in [PHP: variable-length argument list by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925253/php-variable-length-argument-list-by-reference), there is no way in PHP to combine variable-length and pass by reference function arguments. Instead, the linked answer uses a hack of declaring 100 `&argx`s, then using `get_num_args()` to figure out how many were actually used. Congratulations, you found a particularly hard corner in PHP ;)

It also shows how to do it with PHP 5.6+ variadics.

Comment: Was accurate until php5.6 in 2014. Markus' answer is more accurate now, since this is supported.

Answer (score 5):

I highly doubt that's possible, but I do know one way you could get what you want:

```
function test(&$args) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $arg .= 'baz';
    }
}

test(array(&$test, &$test2));
```

Comment: It looks like we will soon be able to do this using the new `...` operator in PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$test = 'foo';
$test2 = 'bar';

function test(){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($backtrace[0]['args'] as &$arg)
        $arg .= 'baz';
}

test(&$test, &$test2);
```

However, this uses call-time pass by reference which is deprecated.

Comment: Not allowed at all in PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me when doing something like the example below. I think the key is setting the reference in the foreach.

```
$var1 = '%DIR%/test';

replaceParameters(
    $var1, 
    $var2, 
    $var3
);

function replaceParameters(&$variables) {

    $variables = array_filter(func_get_args());

    $parameters = [
        '%DIR%' => __DIR__, 
        '%FILE%' => __FILE__,
    ];

    foreach($variables as &$variable) {
        $variable = str_replace(array_keys($parameters), array_values($parameters), $variable);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this functionality as well, I came up with a solution.

```
function sayhello($params) {
    //params hold an unlimited amount of references
}

sayhello([&$one, &$two]);
```

This depends on php >= 5.4 though. If you're on <= 5.4, use array() syntax instead of [].

I love [] tho, much better :)

Comment: You pass exactly one argument which is an array (and worked beside that syntax in <PHP-5.4 as well). This is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Using objects is the solution

```
class O {
    public $v;
    public function __construct(&$p){
        $this->v = &$p;
    }
}

function append_baz_to_all(){
    foreach(func_get_args() as &$arg){
        $arg->v .= 'baz';
    }
}

function test1(){
    echo "test1\n";
    $a='A';$b='B';$c='C';$d='D';$e='E';$f='F';$g='G';
    echo("\$a=$a \$b=$b \$c=$c \$d=$d \$e=$e \$f=$f \$g=$g\n");
    append_baz_to_all(new O($a), new O($b));
    echo("\$a=$a \$b=$b \$c=$c \$d=$d \$e=$e \$f=$f \$g=$g\n\n");
}

//shortcutting
function o(&$v){return new O($v);}

function test2(){
    echo "test2\n";
    $a='A';$b='B';$c='C';$d='D';$e='E';$f='F';$g='G';
    echo("\$a=$a \$b=$b \$c=$c \$d=$d \$e=$e \$f=$f \$g=$g\n");
    append_baz_to_all(o($c), o($d), o($e));
    echo("\$a=$a \$b=$b \$c=$c \$d=$d \$e=$e \$f=$f \$g=$g\n\n");
}


test1();
test2();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function byref_alias()
{
 //$argz=func_get_args(); //byval, not what you want
 $argz=debug_backtrace()[0]['args']; //byref hack
 $argz[0]++; works
}
```

Comment: Remember that although these arguments are byreference, they do not modify the original argument sent to the function, but they will be sent byreference.