# Passing by reference is not working as expected

Tags: php, reference

Why in the below simplified Plugins system example, passing by reference ($data) is not working ($content is not modified)?

```
class Plugins
{
    public static function runhook()
    {
       $args = func_get_args();
       $hook = array_shift($args);
       foreach ($args as &$a); // be able to pass $args by reference
       call_user_func_array(array('Plugin', $hook), $args);
    }

}

class Plugin
{
    public static function modifData(&$data)
    {
       $data = 'Modified! :'.$data;
    }
}

class Application
{
    public $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->content = 'Content from application...';
    }

    public function test()
    {
       echo $this->content; // return 'Content from application...'
       Plugins::runHoook('modifData', $this->content);
       echo $this->content; // return 'Content from application...' instead of 'Modified! :Content from application...'

    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->test();
```

As you can see $this->content should be modified by the modifData() called in background by runHook() function of the Plugin class. But for a strange reason nothing expected happens and the variable stay stuck in his original state... Maybe I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: `Plugins::runHoook` shouldn't that be `Plugins::runHook`?

Comment: IT's because you are only passing by reference to the Plugin class. Plugins::runHook isn't recieving a reference

Comment: FWIT, you can just pass the whole object because objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oops that's just a typo...

Comment: @Pinoniq Thanks for the explanation i will try in the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with a variable amount of paramters (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035513/684353).

You could achieve it with this (repeat this for the amount of parameters you're expecting, which shouldn't be too many):

```
<?php

class Plugins
{
    public static function runHook($hook, &$param1)
    {
       $args = func_get_args();
    //   call_user_func_array(array('Plugin', $hook), [$param1]); // doesn't work, probably can fix this but didn't seem necessary 
       Plugin::$hook($param1);
    }

}

class Plugin
{
    public static function modifData(&$data)
    {
       $data = 'Modified! :'.$data;
    }
}

class Application
{
    public $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->content = 'Content from application...';
    }

    public function test()
    {
       echo $this->content; // return 'Content from application...'
       Plugins::runHook('modifData', $this->content);
       echo $this->content; // return 'Content from application...' instead of 'Modified! :Content from application...'

    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->test();
```

Or wait for PHP 5.6 and hope the [... token](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) will allow this.

Comment: Oh okay, so I could search for a very long time if it's just not possible! Thank you for the explanation, i'll try something based on your example :)