# PHP - push_to_array function

Tags: php, arrays

So i have following function :

```
function push_to_array()
{
    $array_of_data = func_get_arg(0);
    for($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i){

        $array_of_data[] = func_get_arg($i);
    }
    return $array_of_data;
}
```

I can use it with existing array : `$array = ['once','two','three'];`

Function is  used for pushing data into existing array.

So final call looks like :

```
$newArray = push_to_array($array,'haha','hoho','hihi');
```

Now i want to transform the call into

`push_to_array($array,'haha','hoho','hihi');`

so i dont need to create new variable or i dont want to, but i want to modify already existing array;

**PS**: i know there are functions like **array_push** but i want to learn it by myself.

Comment: *"i know there are functions like array_push but i want to learn it by myself."* -- I love this. Good luck on your PHP adventures, Peter. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass unlimited arguments by reference in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026872/how-to-pass-unlimited-arguments-by-reference-in-php)

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the same variable:

```
$array = push_to_array($array,'haha','hoho','hihi');
```

But to answer the question, you will need to use [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so you must include it as an argument:

```
function push_to_array(&$array_of_data)
{
    for($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i){    
        $array_of_data[] = func_get_arg($i);
    }
}
```

However this will achieve the same as the first example:

```
$array = array_merge($array,['haha','hoho','hihi']);
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.6 or later, you can form variable-length functions using the ellipsis:

```
function push_to_array(array &$a, ...$elems) {
    foreach ($elems as $elem) {
        $a[] = $elem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variable by reference :

```
function push_to_array(&$array_of_data)
{
    for($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i){

        $array_of_data[] = func_get_arg($i);
    }
    return $array_of_data;
}

$array = ['once','two','three'];

 push_to_array($array,'haha','hoho','hihi');

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

[You're wanting to pass the variable as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

```
function my_array_push(&$arr, ...$values) {
    while (($val = array_pop($values)) !== null) {
        $arr[] = $val;
    }
}

$t = [1];
my_array_push($t, [2, 3, 4]);
var_dump($t); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

- [More information on passing a variable as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)
- [... In PHP (variable length arguments)](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

*I didn't see that you were aware of array_push before positing the following*

For what it is worth, the functionality that you are trying to create is provided by [the default array_push function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
$a = [1];

array_push($a, 2, 3, 4);

var_dump($a); // [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   function self_coded_push_to_array(&$array){
      // get all arguments
      $args = func_get_args();
      foreach($args as $i => $arg){
         // not the first argument (that's the array)
         if($i > 0){
            // add to the array
            $array[] = $arg;
         }
      }
    }


    $arr = array('donkey','monkey');

    self_coded_push_to_array($arr, 'zebra', 'whale');

    print_r($arr);
```

This returns:

```
Array (
 [0] => donkey,
 [1] => monkey,
 [2] => zebra,
 [3] => whale
)
```

Comment: really interesting solution, thanks for coming here !