# Variable-length by-ref argument lists in functions

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, argument-passing, variadic-functions

In PHP you can do this:

```
function something() {
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg)
    echo $arg;
}
something(1, 3); //echoes "13"
```

This works fine for arguments passed by value, but what if I want them to be passed by reference? like this:

```
function something_else() {
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg)
    $arg *= 2;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
something_else($a, $b);
echo $a . $b; //should echo "26", but returns "13" when I try it
```

Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: variable-length argument list by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925253/php-variable-length-argument-list-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems horrible, but lets humour you. Below is a **horrible hack**, but you could send across a single argument which contains the items that you want to work with.

```
function something_else($args) {
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
        $arg *= 2;
    }
}
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
something_else(array(&$a, &$b));
echo $a . $b; // 26
```

Comment: well, it's an idea.. just out of curiosity, do you know if this is possible in other languages?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot. The declaration of a prameter passed by ref is explicit as `function something(&$arg1, &$arg2)`. If you don't know the number of parameters at compile time, you can do something like this:

```
function something_else($args) {
      foreach ($args as $arg)
        $GLOBALS[$arg] *= 2;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
something_else(array('a', 'b'));
echo $a . $b; //returns "26"
```

Basically the code passes to the function the names of the params the function will modify. `$GLOBALS` holds references to all defined variables in the global scope of the script. This means if the call is from another function it will not work:

```
function something_else($args) {
      foreach ($args as $arg)
        $GLOBALS[$arg] *= 2;
}

function other_function(){
    $a = 1;
    $b = 3;
    something_else(array('a', 'b'));
    echo $a . $b; //returns "13"
}
other_function();
```

triggers notices undefined indexes `a` and `b`. So another approach is to create an array with references to the variables the function will modify as:

```
function something_else($args) {
      foreach ($args as &$arg)
        $arg *= 2;
}

function other_fucntion(){
    $a = 1;
    $b = 3;
    something_else(array(&$a, &$b));
    echo $a . $b; //returns "26"
}
other_fucntion();
```

Note the `&` on the `foreach` line. It is needed so not to create a new variable iterating over the array. PHP > 5 needed for this feature.

Comment: I *really* don't want to use $GLOBALS, and if passing a single array is the only solution, salathe's answer is much cleaner..

Comment: It is absolutely the same idea. I just pointed out the limitations of `$GLOBALS`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way but it uses call-time pass by reference which is deprecated in PHP 5.3:

```
function something_else() {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    foreach($backtrace[0]['args'] as &$arg)
    $arg *= 2;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
something_else(&$a, &$b);
echo $a . $b;
```